# Telegram bot doesn't receive forwarded message

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I've created a telegram bot.
Everything works fine and I can receive updates.
Except for when you forward a message to it, it doesn't receive it.
any Ideas?

I have set the webhook and get updates like this:

```
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

after this, I process updates normally, but only direct messages arrive. and Forwarded messages dont.

Comment: Please read [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: I'm running about 4 bots and I don't have this problem, How do you store your updates and check for the forwarded message?

Answer (score 1):

Bots can not detect messages from other bots.
some members forward message from bots then your bot can not receive it.